"can-do" vs. "can-explain" fallacy
Is there a name for the fallacy where, if someone is not able to explain how he or she does something, it is taken as a proof that he/she can't actually do it?
For example, I once claimed in an argument that a photograph was staged (as opposed to authentic). My opponent rhetorically asked, how could I see whether a photograph was staged or authentic - the implication being that if I can't explain it, I can't say a staged photograph from an authentic one.
It is obvious to me that this is a fallacy: I can't describe my mother precisely enough for a stranger to recognise her, but I can recognise her myself among thousand other women - and, since I was a normal, healthy child, I was probably able to do it when I was a baby, long before I could speak.
Or, a more extreme example: My dog can pretty accurately recognise me, but he will never be able to explain how he does it.
Also, I can't write a grammar for my native language, but I speak it pretty flawlessly. I could go on and on...
Update
It seems to me that the fallacy is related to the ad ignorantiam fallacy, as my opponent is challenging me to produce a better argument. However, it is also different in that my opponent is not presenting any evidence him/herself, beyond simply saying "it's impossible".
Update (2)
I'm perfectly aware that the burden of proof of being able to do something is on me, and, in real life, I'd offer to prove it in a test, like in the  Fisher's "Lady tasting tea". For example, I could take a large staple of photos and try identifying the staged ones, or, in case of the dog, set up many different test situations where the dog is required to identify me. This is nothing new, we do it all the time, whether for testing our machine learning algorithms or for approving new medical treatments.
What I have an issue with is the "intellectual" attitude (hat tip to @Conifold) that if I can't explain it, I can't do it. That is obviously a non sequitur, as my examples with babies, dogs, and grammar show, and I could list many more. Even in cases where I can offer some kind of an explanation, who's to say that the explanation is true? It may just as well be a rationalisation of my unconscious mental processes. To my knowledge, that's what current developments in psychology are pointing towards: Our decisions are mostly unconscious processes, happening before we become aware of them.
In consequence, I disagree with the sentiment voiced in some of the comments that I should be able to offer at least some kind of an explanation how I do something. I don't know whether Ms. Bristol offered an explanation how she recognised whether milk or tea was poured first into the cup, but even if she did, that explanation was irrelevant for the fact that she really could do it - as was empirically proven.
So, I'm not asking how I should react in a discussion when someone challenges my claimed ability to do something. I know he or she has the right to doubt me and I know - at least in principle - how to dispel these doubts. I just want to know whether it is a known, common phenomenon for which there is an established name.
Also, I'm not convinced that having a name for a fallacy doesn't serve any purpose. Otherwise, we wouldn't have lists of common fallacies.
Update (3)
To formalise the argument, let D denote the sentence "A can do X" and E "A can explain how he/she/it does X". The argument in question is:

The argument is valid. However, recall that
, and I've shown examples above of the latter not being actually true. Therefore, the second premise is also not true, making the whole argument not sound.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Whilst this is a fascinating example and topic of discussion, OP, I feel the use of the term "fallacy" is let us say misplaced. (You seem to think that all philosophical situations or discussions can be categorized in to "Fallacy X" from a list; there's no such list, nobody cares about "fallacies", and there are "one or two, maybe three, famous catchphrases that happen to have the word fallacy in them" but other than that it doesn't have much to do with anything.

@Fattie "there's no such list" ? List of Fallacies.

Cheers @JimmyJames I would have thought the sentence was pretty clear: You seem to think that all philosophical situations or discussions can be categorized in to "Fallacy X" from a list; there's no such list  So we're looking at "all philosophical situations .. all philosophical discussions".  "Fallacies" (such as the example list you give) have little or nothing to do with the topic.

@Fattie I do think that statements like "there's no such list", "nobody cares about 'fallacies'" and " and there are 'one or two, maybe three, famous catchphrases that happen to have the word fallacy in them'" seem pretty clear.  (I'm not sure what the quotes are about in the last one, though.)  So, are you saying when you say "there's no such list" that you don't mean "a list of fallacies doesn't exist"?  What does, "there's no such list" mean, then? Is this a British English versus AmE thing?

JJ - The sentence was "You seem to think that all philosophical situations or discussions can be categorized in to "Fallacy X" from a list; there's no such list".  It's perfectly clear. There is no "list of fallacies" into which one can categorize all philosophical situations. The OP believes: "1. Here is a philosophical challenge or issue.  2. The solution or reply to (1.) is a certain Fallacy ('from [some] list of well known fallacies ...')." Fallacies (if anything) are just "a topic you sometimes hear mentioned in rhetoric" and not some central paradigm in philosophy. Repetition now, cheers

@Fattie There are far more that 2 or 3 fallacies that are quite well defined and I disagree that they have nothing to do with this.  I don't know what catchphrases you are referring to or why that is relevant at all.

Have you seen Prediction-Explanation fallacy. Also the more traditional Illusion of Explanatory Depth

This is probably not a fallacy
You and your friend are operating from different premises, which means that you can each reach different conclusions even if you both follow entirely valid logic.
You are taking as a premise (from your senses and intuition) that the image is fake. Your friend does not accept this as a premise, so they ask for evidence to support it. You are unable to provide that evidence, because it comes from senses and instinct. At this point, deductive logic can no longer help you reach agreement - and continuing to argue will look like a fallacy to both sides.
From your friend's perspective, it looks like you're making an Argument from Authority
The Argument from authority looks something like this:

X is knowledgeable, trustworthy, and reliable.
X believes Y.
Therefore Y.

In this case, you are asserting that you are trustworthy, knowledgeable, and reliable in the domain of detecting fake or staged images, therefore if you believe an image is fake, it is fake.
This is a fallacy because credible people are not infallible. In order to convince others, a credible person must be able to point to evidence that justifies their belief. Additionally, your friend may have a different opinion about your credibility.
Therefore, in asserting that the image is fake because it looks fake to you, you have committed the Argument from Authority Fallacy (from your friend's perspective).
From your perspective, it looks like your friend is Affirming the Consequent
Affirming the consequent has the following form:

X implies Y
Not X
Therefore, not Y.

This is a fallacy because implications only go one way. If X implies Y, that does not mean that "Not X" implies "Not Y." It could be the case that Y is still true even without X.
It's true that if you had evidence to prove the image was fake, then it must be fake. However, it is not the case that the image is real just because you can't prove that it is false.
In asserting that the image is real because you cannot prove that it is fake, your friend has committed the Affirming the Consequent Fallacy (from your perspective).
Hunting for fallacies is unproductive here
A useful concept here is the Burden of Proof. In casual discussions, the burden of proof is held by whomever is trying to change the other person's mind - which often means both people have the burden of proof simultaneously. Your friend doesn't have to prove that the image is real to justify not changing their mind, but they do if they want you to change yours. Similarly, you don't have to prove that the image is fake to justify not changing your mind, but you do if you want your friend to change theirs.
The burden of proof is called a "burden," but I prefer to think of it as a privilege. To make an analogy to sports: Whomever has the burden of proof is on the offense. Their position is more difficult, but they are capable of scoring points. The person who doesn't have the burden of proof is on defense. Their position is easier, but the best they can do is take the burden of proof back.
In this situation, I see four options:

Cede the claim on the image in exchange for burden of proof. "Okay, let's suppose that the image is real, but even so, you should still change your mind because [other reason]."
Cede the burden of proof in exchange for the claim on the image, "I don't think that image is very convincing, but I won't try to change your mind about it."
Pause the debate to gather more evidence, and continue once you and your friend have had time to prepare a case for why the image should or shouldn't be accepted as valid.
Accept that neither of you is going to change the other's mind, and end the discussion.


I believe we're all accepting arguments from authority, all the time: Smoking is a health risk, climate change is real, elevators are safe... You certainly haven't proven any of these yourself (otherwise you wouldn't be wasting your time on Philosophy SE), much less all of them. So the issue is that my opponent (who isn't my friend - what's the name of the fallacy for assuming he is?) is not accepting me as an authority, for the same reason why Ronald Fisher didn't believe that smoking was dangerous (https://priceonomics.com/why-the-father-of-modern-statistics-didnt-believe/).

@IgorF. An argument from authority means that you'd claim something to be true because of the authority of the person claiming it. But that's not the case. You're not supposed to "believe in these things because a smart person said them". You're free and encouraged to look at the data, the math, the ideas, the experiments and so on. Few people end up doing that, but that is not a problem of the person making the argument it is THEIR problem. It's your heuristic, you save time not researching and you pay the price in a lack of agency and ability to assess how wrong or correct you are.

@IgorF. For that matter Fisher was able to follow the methodology of his peer and criticize it, he was not meant to accept it at face value because of any authority. Though there are usually two error that you can make, one is accepting the hypothesis despite it being wrong the other is rejecting it despite it being correct. And you might have ethical not necessarily statistical discussions about what you should prevent more.

@IgorF. I'd argue that trusting the word of an authoritative figure isn't in itself inherently fallacious. When it becomes fallacious is when you are encouraged to disregard existing evidence (or lack thereof) in favor of their word. Accepting the authoritative figure's word with the reasonable assumption that evidence to support it exists and that, should it prove necessary, it can be located without too much difficulty is a necessary factor in virtually any debate. Otherwise 99.99% of all formal debates would be spent recursively fact-checking every claim ever made regardless of who made it.

If this person is not your friend and has no prior history with you, then expecting them to accept your assertion about the falseness of an image based entirely on your own credibility seems absurd to me. It may not be a formal fallacy, but there's a very old internet meme about that sort of argument. It goes something like "This looks shopped. I can tell from some of the pixels and because I've seen a lot of shops in my time," and is usually posted as a troll/shitpost rather than as a serious argument.

I'm also not sure I understand your headline "this is probably not a fallacy" when you later point to a page that says that affirming the consequence "is a formal fallacy."  I also don't see anywhere in the question that the 'opponent' stated it must be a real picture.

@JimmyJames - Fallacies are ways of reaching incorrect conclusions from a set of correct premises. When two people are arguing from different sets of premises, they will reach different conclusions even if neither one commits a fallacy - however, it will look like a fallacy if they assume that the other side is using the same premises they are. This "looks like" affirming the consequent, but what's actually going on is that the consequent has been noted as an unshared premise.

@TimC But arguing that someone cannot claim a picture is fake unless they can show how it was faked is a logical fallacy per your definition. It's not even the case that being able to show how something could be faked is proof that it was.

@JimmyJames - I assume that people are allowed to accept premises from their senses. If someone sees a sheep with their own two eyes, then it's reasonable for them to include the existence of that sheep in their premises, even if they cannot prove that sheep's existence otherwise. The "I believe it's fake because I can see it's fake" instinct pattern is similar. The issue is that accepting premises from your own senses isn't the same as expecting that everyone else to accept the same premises.

This is where burden of proof comes in - if Alice wants to convince Bob, then she has to show that her conclusion follows from the premises Bob accepts, without bringing in any of her own premises unless she can first convince Bob to accept them.

@TimC I absolutely agree with you but, as I see it, that's a different question. If I offer photographic evidence and you tell me you won't accept it as evidence because you think it is (or might be) fake, it's on me to show that it is authentic (which may not be possible.) But if I instead claim that you must either demonstrate how it was faked or accept it as authentic, I am using a fallacious argument. The OP has made it clear that last part is all that is being asked about here.

@TimC I'm surely not the only one who sees what a pertinent question this is in 2024CE.  On one hand, we have generative AI which brings so all photographic and video evidence into question.  On the other hand, I also see a problem with dismissing 'fake news' whenever evidence is presented. All of this makes coming to a consensus more challenging.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Being able to perform some action and being able to explain (in some level of detail) how one is performing or able to perform that action are, generally speaking, clearly two different capabilities. The claim "If you cannot explain how you are doing such and such, you're not really able to do such and such" is clearly wrong in almost all cases. To argue that it is wrong, it suffices to give one acceptable counter-example. Another way of arguing that it is wrong, is to propose a different method of showing that you can indeed perform the challenged action (have the skill or ability to do such-and-such), for instance performing a blind, controlled test.
In many cases however, that claim is also, clearly, not completely wrong. In particular not when applied to humans. If you (assuming you are a human) are not able to say anything sensible and acceptable about how you are doing such-and-such, then it can be reasonably doubted whether you are able to do so. For instance, if you claim to be able to recognize that a particular photo is a fake (AI generated or manipulated, etc) rather than real, and you cannot point out any aspects that make you suspicious, then the other can reasonably doubt whether you are able to recognize the photo as such rather than making a random guess. (It may still be the case that you are able to reliably distinguish fakes from non-fakes, of course, but more evidence is needed.)
As far as I know there is no commonly used term for the fallacy expressed in the general claim. If you want to coin a term for it, you could perhaps call it "the explicative fallacy", the fallacy that mistakenly identifies an ability (or skill, which may be a cognitive skill) with being able to explain that ability (or skill).
However, relying on this term, or the mere fact that you now have a term, to strengthen any argument against the fallacy that the term is presumed to refer to, is itself a form of relying on a fallacy, the so-called nominal fallacy.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I think maybe the fallacy in question here, or close to it, is an appeal to accomplishment
I've run into this a number of times. For example, I might say something about a popstar not being a good singer and the response is: "I'd like to see you do better." I can't, because I am also not a very good singer but that really doesn't have any bearing on my claim. Being as good, or better, than me at singing does not make one a good singer.
But I'm not completely sure that this is exactly right. The argument that this person seems to be making is that if you don't know the exact way the photo was staged, you cannot claim that it was staged. But in order to show that a photo was staged or faked, you don't have to know that. You could, for example, point to some detail which is inconsistent with the real world such as the sun casting shadows in two directions.  An obviously absurd version of this is claiming that you can't know someone was in a building because you don't know which way they entered.

Thanks. I agree that it's related, but not identical. Appeal to accomplishment would be something like: "You can't know that the photo is staged because you can't stage it yourself", right?

There is the "explain vs justify" dichotomy. I see a lot of it in the programming world. Take some mainstream old n barnacled language and point out some really problematic feature. Immediately some fanboy will pipe up with a convoluted historical trajectory explaining why that feature has to be that way and no other. And I'm always at a loss to explain why an explanation is not a justification

@IgorF. Yes, I think that's the most straightforward way. In that page there's this "The reverse, appealing to the fact that no one has the proper experience in question and thus cannot prove something is impossible, is a version of an argument from silence." which also seems related until I look at the detail of the page.  I don't know if there's a name for this. It's kind of saying that claiming a magic trick is an illusion is wrong unless you know how the trick works and that's obviously not the case.

@Rushi I think I know what you mean. Not too long ago, I questioned the need for 3VL as implemented in SQL. I didn't get any answers about why it has to be that way (that's what I was looking for) but rather that I must not understand how nulls work in SQL.  But if it actually 'has to be that way' it does kind of justify it, right?

3 valued logic is a bit different in that its deeper and more philosophical issue than (say) why C++ templates have such horrible syntax or why Python varianles leak in list comprehensions. The problem with 3vl is why not 4vl? If 4vl then why not 5vl? Etc. A typical eg. I take is a nullable phone number. Does a null signify that the data is not entered? Or that the party actually has no phone? An instance of a 4vl would be signaling vs quiet NANs

@Rushi I have a general understanding of 3VL, 4VL, etc. and I know that what exists in SQL isn't fully formed (relative to the theory concept behind it.) But that wasn't the question. The question was about the practical value of the 'feature'.  In other words, I was looking for examples it helping to solve problems, not how to avoid problems with it. I really don't want to get into it here, though.

@IgorF. I had another thought about this.  Again, not exactly on target but this seems related to 'god of the gaps' style arguments.

When in doubt, it's always called: Non sequitur.
Person A claims that "From [being able to perform a task] follows [that you're able to explain it]". Now give them the example of the baby or the dog. Hence as it does not follow in this case, you can not conclude that it follows in every case, and thus it is not a universal law that being able to perform a task entails that you're able to explain it.
Though it also reveals a problem with calling out fallacies, in that they are meant to strike down logical deductions, claims of certainties and universal laws from which you can reliably follow certain conclusions.
While in the real world those are rarely ever found in the wild outside of neat reservations like logic, math and other fantasy realms. So already your claim that:

I don't know whether Ms. Bristol offered an explanation how she recognised whether milk or tea was poured first into the cup, but even if she did, that explanation was irrelevant for the fact that she really could do it - as was empirically proven.

Is fallacious as empiricism cannot possibly "proof" that. Even if Ms. Bristol drank all the tea and all the milk in the universe it is still unclear whether she was actually able to tell which was added first or if she just got incredibly lucky (or if she just cheated).
It doesn't follow from plurality of data that something must indeed be a universal law. Like for example your friend or foe or adversary or whatnot might have made plenty of experience with plenty of people telling that they can tell staged from real and they all turned out to be wrong, is he thus justified in believing that it cannot be done?
Well no he isn't able to make that conclusion, but he isn't able to conclude that it is possible either, so they are forced to make a decision the heuristic of going with the majority of experience and distrusting your otherwise unfounded claim is probably a reasonable first approach.
And similar to that lots of things that are ultimately fallacious can nonetheless be reasonable heuristics that work often enough to be considered as default and to be relied on (not in the logical, but the colloquial sense that keeps in mind that there is still always a risk left that you're wrong).
The other thing is that when you've already left the realm of certainties and venture into the realm of the speculations and probabilities, you a) would need to accept a more or less arbitrary  threshold of trust as to what is "beyond just being lucky" and b) realize that you could make two different kinds of error, one in accepting what is false and one in rejecting what is true and depending on what proposition you're evaluating you might have a preference for one error or the other.
Like famously for tests for diseases you'd rather have false positives so healthy people being pronounced ill, than to have false negatives where sick people remain undetected and for example continue to spread a virus. Or in your example you might want to warn about tobacco being potentially dangerous rather than wait till evidence is undeniable as millions of people have already died.
